# What is the resource qualifier for 1080p phones?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I am trying to prepare our latest app for a 1080p device HTC is announcing.

When 320ppi devices came out (e.g. Galaxy Nexus), Google added the xhdpi qualifier.

The new crop of devices coming out, including the announced HTC device, are of significantly higher screen density.  In this case, the devices are ~440ppi.  For these devices, do we continue using the xhdpi qualifier and account for scaling or is there a different qualifier to use, such as xxhdpi?

Answer (score 1):

I was under the impression that we would continue using xhdpi for now but according to [Google's Compatibility Definition](http://source.android.com/compatibility/4.1/android-4.1-cdd.pdf), xxhdpi is already supported in Android 4.1.  (Scroll to section 7.1.1 in the linked PDF.)

Also, API support for the new bucket can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_XXHIGH).

This density bucket isn't widely talked about since 1080p phones are just starting to come out but it IS supported and listed for phone densities in the ~480ppi range.  440 is closer to 480 than 320 so xxhdpi would be the bucket that these 1080p phones fall into per the compatibility guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

The newer standard of using `sw` to signify min-width in dp seems to be the way forward to copy with all the stranger combinations.

Comment: The density identifiers like mdpi and xhdpi are still used for specifying resources though.  The sw buckets are mostly used for layouts in my experience.

Comment: True, however bigger images are going to require massive memory improvements.